# Android lib/ folder, multiple architectures, and directory structure

Tags: android, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, apk, directory-structure

I have native/JNI source code I need to test on Android. I've created a project from the command line using `android create project...`, and its directory structure is as described at Android's [Managing Projects](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html).

However, I'm having trouble locating official documentation on adding native libraries with different architectures to the layout.

Suppose I have a base `libfoo.so` for ARMv4T. That covers all Android devices, and it goes in `lib/`. But how about the ARMv6 and ARMv7 versions of `foo`? What is the logical layout and/or naming for them?

Does Android want the ARMv6 version of `foo` at `libs/armv6/libfoo.so`, ARMv7 version of `foo` at `libs/armv7/libfoo.so`, and the ARMv7a version of `foo` at `libs/armv7a/libfoo.so`? Or does Android want something like `libs/libfoo-armv6.so` and `libs/libfoo-armv7a.so`?

Comment: I use "armeabi-v7a" and "armeabi" and "mips" and "x86" folder under libs folder to cover all types

Comment: You need to create a folder for each and every architecture variant within the JNI folder and place the respective .so files in them. The file names can be the same(libfoo.so) but they need to be placed in different directories like jni/libs/x86, jni/libs/armv4 etc

Comment: @G3M - According to David Turner at [Shared library not included in apk file](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-ndk/yx_5-RNGAoU/63IfHAuLHXcJ), I believe they need to `libs/x86` (the root `libs` directory), and not `jni/libs/x86` (within the `jni` folder).

Comment: @jww My bad! I meant libs folder not jni/libs.